# css wave animation for chat messages

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a wave animation. The ones you see in chat messages that indicates whether or not a person is currently typing. However, my animation doesn't quite look like what i'm trying to achieve.

**What I'm trying to do:**

[image]

**The problem**

- The animation becomes a straight line at the highest and lowest point.
- The animation doesn't look fluid. It stops at certain points.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #3e6b61;
    }
    
    .is-typing {
      margin-top: 100px;
      width: 50px;
      justify-content: space-around;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .jump1,
    .jump2,
    .jump3 {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .jump1 {
      animation: typing 4s infinite;
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .jump2 {
      animation: typing 4s infinite;
      animation-delay: .2s;
    }
    
    .jump3 {
      animation: typing 4s infinite;
      animation-delay: .4s;
    }
    
    @keyframes typing {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        background-color: gray;
      }
      33% {
        transform: translateY(20px);
      }
      66% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="is-typing">
    <div class="jump1"></div>
    <div class="jump2"></div>
    <div class="jump3"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: take look at this: [Wavy Preloader Animation with CSS](https://w3bits.com/css-wavy-preloader/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to start transformY with minus value and maybe change animation time in % so u can make it faster if u need it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <style>
      body {
         background-color: #3e6b61;
      }

      .is-typing {
         margin-top: 90px;
         width: 85px;
         justify-content: space-around;
         display: flex;
      }

      .jump1,
      .jump2,
      .jump3,
      .jump4,
      .jump5 {
         width: 10px;
         height: 10px;
         border-radius: 100%;
         background-color: gray;
      }

      .jump1 {
         animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
         animation-delay: 01.1s;
      }

      .jump2 {
         animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
         animation-delay: 01.2s;
      }

      .jump3 {
         animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
         animation-delay: 01.3s;
      }

      .jump4 {
         animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
         animation-delay: 01.4s;
      }

      .jump5 {
         animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
         animation-delay: 1.5s;
      }

    @keyframes typing {
     0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
     }

     25% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
     }

     35% {
        transform: translateY(15px);
     }

     45% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
     }

     60% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
     }

     75% {
          background-color: white;
        transform: translateY(0px);
     }

     100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
     }
  }
   </style>
</head>

<body>

   <div class="is-typing">
      <div class="jump1"></div>
      <div class="jump2"></div>
      <div class="jump3"></div>
      <div class="jump4"></div>
      <div class="jump5"></div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```